# Is it possible to do dynamic clustering with Jackrabbit

Tags: postgresql, jackrabbit

Scenario:

- Running Jackrabbit (version 2.10) in a cluster with a Postgres DB.
- Have Docker containers being orchestrated by K8s or Marathon.
- Each container joins the Jackrabbit cluster with unique cluster node id (repository.xml).
- The container may be up for a brief period of time or a long period of time, depending on what task it is running inside. *Thus each container joins cluster as jackrabbit node*.
- we have no upper limit on number of currently running containers that may join.

Is it feasible to be constantly joining  and leaving a jackrabbit cluster. 
Are there any known issue that may occur?
Am trying to get ahead of issues that may arise when exercising the above. 
Any thoughts at all would be appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to get the answer?